# Etymology of fruit names (the unusual formation of berry fruit names and the indigenous fruits of England)

Tags: etymology, food

I am from Italy. Italy has a warmer climate than England, and some fruits that naturally grow in Italy (and maybe they do not naturally grow in England) have an English name that sounds a lot like the Italian one:

| Italian | English |
| --- | --- |
| Pesca | Peach |
| Albicocca | Apricot |
| Limone | Lemon |
| Arancia | Orange |
| Pera | Pear |
| Prugna | Plum |
| Ciliegia | Cherry |

On the other hand, all the "berries" (berry fruits) have very different names:

| Italian | English |
| --- | --- |
| Fragola | Strawberry |
| Mirtillo | Blueberry |
| Mirtillo rosso | Cranberry |
| Lampone | Raspberry |
| Mora | Blackberry |

Possibly, all the berries are indigenous to England.

It seems to me that the indigenous fruits have indigenous names while the imported fruits borrowed their names from outside.

Is this a sound argument? Or is it something else?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cranberry#Etymology) says that "cranberry" comes from German "kraanbere". Have you tried checking dictionaries for the etymologies of the rest?

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, neither blueberries nor cranberries are indigenous to England.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cranberry) has "In Britain, cranberry may refer to the native species *Vaccinium oxycoccos*, while in North America, cranberry may refer to *Vaccinium macrocarpon*.

Comment: Italian is considered the most direct descendant of Latin (possibly second to Sardinian in phonetics) and it is like a continuation of Latin and Ancient Greek. Thus, most words are directly coming from Latin or Vulgar Latin with small changes. English has a more complicated history and and heavily influenced by German and French (hence it is a Germanic language). Although, the interesting part of your question is the _berry_ words in English where most of them has an unusual formation or a first element. There seems to be folk etymology going on in many berry words. _Strawberry_ is a mystery.

Comment: Have you cherry-picked these examples? What about apples (*mele*), quince (*cotogna*), which are different. Or mulberry (*mora*), which is similar?

Comment: I would guess that if you looked at all fruit names, you'd find more indigenous fruits with English-derived names than imported fruits with English-derived names.  But there are exceptions in both directions: the *pineapple* and the *passion fruit* are indigenous to South America, but have "descriptive" English names.  The *currant* is likely native to Britain, but has a (maybe) imported name.

Comment: This is actually a very good question and it requires a good analysis of both the etymology of fruit names (specifically berry fruits which is the main premise of the question) and history of the fruits and their cultivation (which can give clues about the etymology). _Berry_ fruits have many mysteries to uncover.

Comment: It's also interesting to note that of your Italian fruit names, most of them are also derived from loan words: *albicocca* from Arabic, *limone* from Persian/Sanskrit, *arancia* from Persian, *pera*, *prugna* and *ciliegia* from unknown, possibly from Anatolian languages.  Only *pesca* is a Latin-derived.  But the Latin ultimately meant ***Persian** apple*!

Comment: @Juhasz  _Prugna_ and _ciliegia_ are from Latin / Vulgar Latin also. In the end, most words in Italian language are directly of Latin origin. (I think about 70%-75% based on some analysis and sources I've checked). But yeah, it is interesting that some fruit names are from Arabic/Sanskrit/Persian. I believe it can be related to from where these fruits brought to Europe. For example, apricot came from Arabic spoken lands to Europe.

Comment: @ermanen, looks like *prugna* is from Latin *prunum*, *prunum* is from Greek προῦμνον, and that's "of Anatolian origin" (https://www.etymonline.com/word/plum).  *Ciliegia* is also from Greek by way of Latin, and ultimately "A loanword of uncertain origin, considering the intervocalic -σ- either Anatolian or Pre-Greek." (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%BA%CE%B5%CF%81%CE%B1%CF%83%CF%8C%CF%82#Ancient_Greek).  And this all agrees with your summary - none of these fruits is native to Greece or Italy.  They all came from somewhere further to the east, and so did their names.

Comment: Thanks to the economy of gender in Italian, the word for many  fruits is feminine (*pesca, albicocca, mela, arancia*) and the masculine is the name of the tree (*pesco, albicocco, melo, arancio*): peach tree, apricot tree, apple tree, orange tree.

Comment: @StuartF You're right, and grape (_uva_) puzzles me too...

Comment: **About cranberries**: They are indigenous to swamps and bogs in North America https://extension.umaine.edu/cranberries/cranberry-facts-and-history/#:~:text=The%20Cranberry%20(genus%20Vaccinium)%20is,the%20tropics%20in%20both%20hemispheres. That Italian translation. It is a workaround. All berries are most certainly not indigenous to England. You are missing a bunch of them: https://www.pickyourown.org/unusualfruits.htm

Comment: @user888379 — You are right about blueberries, but we have bilberries (Scots blaeberries), although the species are related.

Comment: @ermanen — Thanks for disenchanting me of my dear mother's fanciful origin for strawberry. I gather it's a "black" word.

Comment: Italian *mirtillo* looks like a diminutive of *mirto* which in English is *myrtle*

Comment: "Italian *Fragola* English *Strawberry*" Those belong in the first group because they are phonetically very similar. Doesn't have anything to do with *straw* to say the least.

Comment: A full account of English berry names would have to cover such additional terms as 'barberry', 'bearberry,' 'bilberry', 'chokeberry',  cloudberry', 'cowberry', 'dewberry', 'dogberry', 'elderberry', 'gooseberry', 'honeyberry', 'huckleberry', 'marionberry', 'mulberry', 'pokeberry', 'rowan-berry', 'salmonberry', and 'thimbleberry'.

Comment: ha!  Yeah!   mostly recently discovered that the 'mulberry' can be used to refer to all kinds of different (looking/sized) fruits, categorised as 'a multiple fruit'.  Analogous to that is kind of like how we use the term 'adverb' to mean so many different things!   

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hypothesize that the different forms for *berry* are a consequence of English and Germanic languages' tendency to form compounds at a higher rate, specifically with the word *berry*, a tendency that didn't make its way into Latin or Italian.

### *Berry* comes from Germanic languages

*Berry* is a word inherited from Germanic (OED, "[berry, n.1](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/17972)"). The full etymology uncovers cognates and predecessors in a number of Germanic languages:

> Found, with some variety of form, in all the Germanic languages: with Old English bęrie weak feminine, compare Old Norse ber (Danish bær , Swedish bär ), Old Saxon beri (in wîn-beri ), Middle Dutch bēre , Old High German beri strong neuter, Middle High German ber and bere neuter and feminine, modern German beere feminine. These point to an Old German *bazjo-m , as a byform of *basjo-m , whence Gothic basi neuter (in weina-basi ‘grape’). The s type is also preserved in Middle Dutch beze , modern Dutch bes , also Middle Dutch and modern Dutch bezie feminine. The feminine forms Dutch bēzie and Old English berie answer to a Germanic extended form *basjôn- , *bazjôn- . The ulterior history is uncertain: *bazjo- has been conjecturally referred to *bazo-z bare adj., adv., and n., as if a bare or uncovered fruit, also to the root represented by Sanskrit bhas- to eat.

I understand the Italian word for *berry* to be *bacca* ([Vocabolario Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/bacca)), which comes from the Latin *baca* ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/baca#Latin)). So *berry* and *baca* share a different point of origin at least a couple of thousand years back. Having a different origin doesn't have to result in a different form: *plum* comes through Germanic but retains an indirect relationship with the Latin *pruna* (OED, "[plum, n. and adj.2](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/146028)"). But one tendency in Germanic does come into play in this case to produce forms distinct between English and Italian: forming words through compounds.

### English and more specifically *berry* loves to form compounds

Latin, Italian, and English all have processes for forming words through compounds. However, only English formed many compounds out of the word *berry*. Latin did not form compounds for its different berries to connect berries morphologically. Instead, the Latin/Italian names each have different origins. For instance, *mirtillo* is related to a Greek word for *myrtle*, from Semitic ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/myrtillus#Latin)); *mora* is related to the Greek word for black mulberry or blackberry, whose form goes right back to proto-Indo-European ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%BC%CF%8C%CF%81%CE%BF%CE%BD#Ancient_Greek)). *Baca* did not generate many compounds, including for any of the berries you list.

However, *berry* did generate several compounds in English, including at least one (*strawberry*) that doesn't appear in other Germanic languages. (German uses *Erdbeere*, Dutch *aardbei*, Danish *jordbær*, each compounding but not with a cognate of *straw* ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Erdbeere#German)).) English has many other berries as well: *gooseberry, bilberry, mulberry, crowberry, barberry, bearberry, hag-berry, dingleberry, elderberry*, and still others. The prevalence of the compound for *berry* in English is no surprise; linguist Ingo Plag commented that compounding is "the most productive type of word-formation process in English" (*Word-Formation in English,* p. 131; [Google Books](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Word_Formation_in_English/DrViDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=most%20productive%20type%20of%20word-formation)). While Latin occasionally deigns to form compounds, English does it all the time, from Old English onward. So do other Germanic languages. To use Dutch alongside English using the chart from the question, you can see the general tendency to using a compound form in a Germanic language:

| Dutch | English |
| --- | --- |
| Aardbei | Strawberry |
| Bosbes | Blueberry |
| Veenbes | Cranberry |
| Framboos | Raspberry |
| Braambes (Braam) | Blackberry |

So you can see at least a linguistic tendency in English to form compounds with *berry* that is absent in Italian.<sup>1</sup> In the last section, I'll consider the geographic implications of the question: is this about the difference between fruit availability in southern and northern Europe?

### Considering the geography hypothesis again

Your guess is that indigenous plants in England would share an English or Germanic origin, whereas plants introduced to England would share a Latin origin. That is possible, especially with *lemon*, *orange*, *apricot*, and *peach*, and possibly with other fruits.

There are exceptions. *Mulberry* shows that a fruit from outside England can be adopted as a *berry* anyway. Varieties of the mulberry tree (Latin *morum*, Italian *gelso*) have origins in South Asia and are widely grown in southern Europe, northern Africa, the Middle East, and India ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morus_(plant)#Distribution)). Mulberries perhaps came to England during the Roman period (*[Morus Londinium](https://www.moruslondinium.org/research/timeline)*). Old English did have a word, *more*, used to refer to a mulberry tree ("[more, n.2](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/122170)"). However, *mulberry* occurs in English by the 14th century anyway and replaces *more*; the *mul-* in *mulberry* probably comes from Latin *morum*, but now as a compound with *berry* (OED, "[mulberry, n. and adj.](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/123405)"). So English could take a very old fruit by another name and *berry* it.

*Mulberry* could be compared to *pear*, which was also an import whose name comes from Latin. Where *more* was entirely replaced by *mulberry*, *pear* has remained relatively stable in form. Perhaps *berry* specifically tends to form compounds for anything that is a berry or berry-like, whereas the compound options for non-berry fruit are more limited (e.g., *pearfruit*, which is occasionally used to differentiate fruit from tree but does not replace *pear*).

So I can't completely answer the geographical question, but I would guess that *berry* being particularly prone to compounding in English explains at least part of the difference in forms. That makes the geography hypothesis harder to test.

<sup>1</sup> Beyond the scope of this answer are other food compounds. For instance, does *nut* behave similarly to *berry*? *Hazelnut* is *nocciola* in Italian. *Walnut* is simply *noce* or nut. *Chestnut* is *castagno/a*. If someone wanted to do a more complete study of food geography and etymology, I would recommend looking at other compounds.

Comment: *"Old English did have a word, more, used to refer to a mulberry tree ("more, n.2")."* French for "mulberry" is "mûre". Which came from which?

Comment: French for "hazelnut" is "noisette*, and for "walnut" it's "noix". Hazelnut is like "little walnut".

Answer (score 2):

In English, many berry words can be explained with a linguistic phenomenon called a "cranberry morpheme" in morphology where a bound morpheme or a word element (like in the archetypal example: the *cran-* of *cranberry*) cannot be assigned a meaning nor a grammatical function. Although, it is not always the case as in *blueberry* and *blackberry* where the first element is straightforward. The more unusual berry words with cranberry morphemes are mainly the product of remodeling of foreign words to make them easier to spell and pronounce in English (called *[anglicization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglicisation_(linguistics))* in linguistics) and they tend to have folk etymologies. The book *[For the Love of Language
An Introduction to Linguistics](https://www.google.ca/books/edition/For_the_Love_of_Language/n2_CDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=berry%20etymology%20cranberry%20strawberry%20england%20cultivation&pg=PA119&printsec=frontcover)* (By Kate Burridge, Tonya N. Stebbins · 2019) explains in detail as below:

> ﻿ ***Crans* and *huckles* - more bound morphemes**
>
> Consider the following list of berry words and decide where you might put the morpheme boundaries: *blackberry, blueberry, cranberry, boysenberry, loganberry, goose- berry, strawberry, raspberry*.
>
> Presumably, you want to identify a berry morpheme here. There is no problem in *blackberry* and *blueberry*, but what do you do with *boysen, cran* and *logan*, which in isolation have no meaning? These are examples of special bound morphemes (appropriately dubbed 'cranberry morphemes' or 'cranmorphs'). History can usually shed some light. *Cranberry* derives from the name for the bird, though no one is entirely sure why this fruit is linked to cranes. Less of a problem is *boysen*. True, it's also only meaningful in combination with *berry*, yet its link to the American horticulturist Rudolph Boysen is clear - he developed this hybrid in the 1920s. Similarly, it was Mr Logan who inspired the *loganberry*.
>
> At first blush, *gooseberry* doesn't look problematic, since it appears to be a straightforward compound of *goose* + *berry*. The question is why goose? Are these birds great consumers of berries, or did people choose the name because the rough surface of the berry reminded them of prickly gooseflesh? Researchers have uncovered earlier versions of the word: *groser* and *gozell*. These don't look much like goose at all and probably came from the French word for the berry *groseille*. English speakers are well known for remodelling foreign imports to look like English words and must have changed *groseille* berry into the more linguistically friendly *gooseberry* - the justification would have been the bristly goose-bump textured surface of the berry.
>
> So, what about the *straw* in the *strawberry*? Straw is the name we give to the stalks of threshed crops, something we once used to strew on the floor (and the word is related to *strew* 'to spread or scatter'). One suggestion then for the origin of *strawberry* is that the long trailing runners of the strawberry plant reminded people of pieces of straw on the floor. You could think of the word as 'strewnberry'. Another possibility is that it is a remodelled form of *strayberry* - after all, the runners do stray. Straw was also once used to protect strawberries, yet the wild fruit was called *strawberry* well before it was propagated in gardens. Then again, wild strawberries grow in grassy places and in hay fields, and their external seeds look like straw. There seems no end to the possible suggestions! In fact *strawberry* may well be the result of a combination of these ideas - a kind of lexical bitser, with multiple origins.
>
> The difficulty is deciding how much history should inform our morpheme boundaries. Consider the *raspberry*. Those of you who have picked raspberries and been scratched by their thorns are probably tempted to make a connection with the verb *rasp* 'to grate', and would analyse this as a straightforward compound. However, no connection with *rasp* has ever been established. This task of carving up berry words into morphemes proves difficult. And we haven't even started on bilberries, huckleberries, hurtleberries and whortleberries! Most berry words aren't nearly as obliging as the blackberry or blueberry.

Small round juicy fruits similar in size tend to have a compound name with the second element "berry". *[Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/berry#etymonline_v_11063)* says that *berry* and *apple* are the only native fruit names; and that's why they may have used as generic terms to form fruit names. *[Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/apple)* provides the note below for *apple (n.)*:

> In Middle English and as late as 17c., it was a generic term for all fruit other than berries but including nuts (such as Old English *fingeræppla* "dates," literally "finger-apples;" Middle English *appel of paradis* "banana," c. 1400). Hence its grafting onto the unnamed "fruit of the forbidden tree" in Genesis.

If you delve into the etymology of different fruit names, you may find that they are influenced by the language of the lands where they were brought to Europe or England from also; as in *apricot*, where the word was influenced by Arabic and Spanish. Here is a relevant etymological explanation of *apricot* from *[cs.mcgill.com](https://www.cs.mcgill.ca/%7Erwest/wikispeedia/wpcd/wp/a/Apricot.htm)*:

> The name derives from "*apricock*" and "*abrecox*", through the French *abricot*, from the Spanish *albaricoque*, which was an adaptation of the Arabic *al-burquk*, itself a rendering of the late Greek πρεκοκκια or πραικοκιον, adapted from the Latin *praecox* or *praecoquus*, early, possibly referring to the fruit maturing much earlier in the summer than plums. However, in Argentina and Chile the word for "apricot" is "*damasco*" which probably indicates that to the Argentines the fruit was associated with Damascus.
>
> The apricot originated in northeastern China near the Russian border, not in Armenia as the scientific name suggests. It did arrive in Armenia after moving through central Asia, which took about 3,000 years. The Romans brought it into Europe through Anatolia about 70 BC. While English settlers brought the apricot to the English colonies in the New World, most of modern American production of apricots comes from the seedlings carried to the west coast by Spanish missionaries

Answer (score 1):

All of the fruit you mention have their own etymology. There seems to be no overall rhyme or reason for their current use other than popular convenience.

**Blueberry** did not appear in English until the late 16th century and was then used as a generic name for any bush that grew blue berries.

**Strawberry** appears in English c. 1000 AD, and is given by the OED as “etymology uncertain” (there’s a conjecture that the “straw” refers to the achenes being like small pieces of straw.)

**Raspberry** comes from “raspwood/rasp” which was the original name of unknown origin and which dates from the mid-16th century (It is weakly conjectured that it is from the Middle French noun “rasp” – the carpenter’s tool - in reference to the roughness of the small thorns on the stem)

**Cranberry** is even more recent and from the 17th century. Prior to this the plant was not specifically identified and all bushes of a similar type went under names relating more to where it appeared with suich names as marsh-whorts , fen-whorts , fen-berries , marsh-berries , moss-berries.  Cranberry first arose in the American colonies where it is native and is an anglicisation of the Low German “krônbere”

**Blackberry** is Old English. Its name has survived as it was so common and so edible.

**Cherry** appears in Old English c. 1000 AD as cyrs, ciris and according to the OED:

> Classical Latin had cerasus cherry-tree, cerasum cherry, corresponding to Greek κερασός (also κερασέα, κερασίο) cherry-tree, κεράσιον cherry; according to the Roman writers, so called because brought by Lucullus from Cerasus in Pontus (though some refer the Greek to κέρας, horn). Latin *Ceresea, to which the Romanic and Germanic names alike go back.

Comment: Blueberries are originally American fruits, which explains why they didn't have a name before the 16th century.